# autowired doesn't work in spring.factories SpringFactoriesLoader initialized bean

Tags: java, spring

i have an in interface class called Task.class

```
public interface Task {
}
```

I have implementation class that implements Task.class

```
public class TaskImpl1 implements Task {
     @Autowired
     private Service service;
}
```

I define them in **spring.factories** file

```
com.service.Task=com.service.impl.TaskImpl1
```

When I use `SpringFactoriesLoader.loadFactories(Task.class, null);`
I am able to get TaskImpl1. However, the bean **service** in TaskImpl1 is null.

Comment: Well yes, because those are loaded outside the application context and thus the regular application context features don't apply.

Comment: thanks for the response. Is there a way to both use SpringFactoriesLoader.loadFactories feature and regular application context features together ?

Comment: No. The Spring Factories things are added to the application context to enrich or modify the behavior of it (like generating mocks instead of actual beans etc.). So they are loaded even before an actual active `ApplicationContext` exists. What is the usecase you are trying to solve? Looks like you are using the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: i see. I want to write clearer code. i have multiple jar files. each jar file has an implementation on Task.class. Then I can use  SpringFactoriesLoader.loadFactories to load all implementations from different jars. 
In this case, developers who create new additional jar and tasks doesn't need to touch other code.

Comment: Just use the regular `ServiceLoader` API from Java. In Spring you can then use a `ServiceListFactoryBean` to get a list of all implementation. Of just directly use the `ServiceLoader` to get the beans and do an additional call to the `ApplicationContext` to configure it.

Comment: after testing, i faced the same problem with ServiceListFactoryBean. Because I need to create resources/META-INF/services/com.service.Task file. 
But then service bean is again null.

Comment: That is probably due to that bean returning a `List` instead of objects. As mentioned what you can do is create your own `FactoryBean` (or extend the `ServiceListFactoryBean` make it `ApplicationContextAware` and override the `getObjectToExpose` method. Copy the current implementation and after retrieving the instance from the `ServliceLoader` call `applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().configureBean(instance, null);` then add the resulting bean to the list (instead of the raw instance from the `ServiceLoader`).

Comment: Or write your own `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor` which uses the `ServiceLoader` to load the class, and for each bean register a new bean in the application context. This would probably be the most elegant solution, as they now behave as regular beans.